# The identity API is not supported for this add-in. - Error code 13000 - Outlook Addin

Tags: outlook, office-js, outlook-addin, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

I am creating an SSO Add-in and I am just calling this to give it a try (getAccessToken):

```
async function getUserData() {
  try {
    let usertokenEncoded = await OfficeRuntime.auth.getAccessToken();
    let usertoken = jwt_decode(usertokenEncoded);
    console.log(usertoken);
  } catch (exception) {
    if (exception.code === 13003) {
     
    } else {
      console.log(exception);
    }
  }
}
```

I am receiving an error saying :

```
The identity API is not supported for this add-in. 13000
```

I believe it is something to do with my manifest file and I don't see any trouble with it.

I have put it at the end of the   as per documentation. Here is the code I have used.

```
 <WebApplicationInfo>
        <Id>97d836ee-5c77-4707-9d54-be09716fdxxx</Id>
        <Resource>api://localhost:3000/97d836ee-5c77-4707-9d54-be09716fdxxx</Resource>
        <Scopes>
          <Scope>Files.Read.All</Scope>
          <Scope>offline_access</Scope>
          <Scope>openid</Scope>
          <Scope>profile</Scope>
        </Scopes>
      </WebApplicationInfo>
  </VersionOverrides>
</OfficeApp>
```

I cannot see any problem with it but it doesn't like something. Can anyone spot the problem ?

Here is my office client

[image]

Here is my part of the XML:

```
<VersionOverrides xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides" xsi:type="VersionOverridesV1_0">
  <VersionOverrides xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides" xsi:type="VersionOverridesV1_1">
    <Hosts>
      <Host xsi:type="MailHost">
        <DesktopFormFactor>
          <FunctionFile resid="Commands.Url"/>
          <ExtensionPoint xsi:type="MessageReadCommandSurface">
            <OfficeTab id="TabDefault">
              <Group id="msgReadGroup">
                <Label resid="GroupLabel"/>
                <Control xsi:type="Button" id="msgReadOpenPaneButton">
                  <Label resid="TaskpaneButton.Label"/>
                  <Supertip>
                    <Title resid="TaskpaneButton.Label"/>
                    <Description resid="TaskpaneButton.Tooltip"/>
                  </Supertip>
                  <Icon>
                    <bt:Image size="16" resid="Icon.16x16"/>
                    <bt:Image size="32" resid="Icon.32x32"/>
                    <bt:Image size="80" resid="Icon.80x80"/>
                  </Icon>
                  <Action xsi:type="ShowTaskpane">
                    <SourceLocation resid="Taskpane.Url"/>
                  </Action>
                </Control>
                <Control xsi:type="Button" id="ActionButton">
                  <Label resid="ActionButton.Label"/>
                  <Supertip>
                    <Title resid="ActionButton.Label"/>
                    <Description resid="ActionButton.Tooltip"/>
                  </Supertip>
                  <Icon>
                    <bt:Image size="16" resid="Icon.16x16"/>
                    <bt:Image size="32" resid="Icon.32x32"/>
                    <bt:Image size="80" resid="Icon.80x80"/>
                  </Icon>
                  <Action xsi:type="ExecuteFunction">
                    <FunctionName>action</FunctionName>
                  </Action>
                </Control>
              </Group>
            </OfficeTab>
          </ExtensionPoint>
        </DesktopFormFactor>
      </Host>
    </Hosts>
    <Resources>
      <bt:Images>
        <bt:Image id="Icon.16x16" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/assets/icon-16.png"/>
        <bt:Image id="Icon.32x32" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/assets/icon-32.png"/>
        <bt:Image id="Icon.80x80" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/assets/icon-80.png"/>
      </bt:Images>
      <bt:Urls>
        <bt:Url id="Commands.Url" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/commands.html"/>
        <bt:Url id="Taskpane.Url" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/taskpane.html"/>
      </bt:Urls>
      <bt:ShortStrings>
        <bt:String id="GroupLabel" DefaultValue="Contoso Add-in"/>
        <bt:String id="TaskpaneButton.Label" DefaultValue="Show Taskpane"/>
        <bt:String id="ActionButton.Label" DefaultValue="Perform an action"/>
      </bt:ShortStrings>
      <bt:LongStrings>
        <bt:String id="TaskpaneButton.Tooltip" DefaultValue="Opens a pane displaying all available properties."/>
        <bt:String id="ActionButton.Tooltip" DefaultValue="Perform an action when clicked."/>
      </bt:LongStrings>
    </Resources>
    <WebApplicationInfo>
        <Id>97d836ee-5c77-4707-9d54-be09716fxxxx</Id>
        <Resource>api://localhost:3000/97d836ee-5c77-4707-9d54-be09716fxxxx</Resource>
        <Scopes>
          <Scope>Files.Read</Scope>
          <Scope>openid</Scope>
          <Scope>profile</Scope>
        </Scopes>
  </WebApplicationInfo>
  </VersionOverrides>
  </VersionOverrides>
</OfficeApp>
```

I have also added this code in to check that my client has the requirement set for IdentityAPI and it has :

```
function IsIdentitySupported() {
  if (Office.context.requirements.isSetSupported("IdentityAPI", "1.3")) {
    console.log("Supported");
    
}
else {
    // Provide alternate flow/logic.
}
}
```

Just added my code to a button in React and it still comes back with :

[image]

Just as a side note - this is failing also on outlook on the web with exactly the same error.

When I create scaffold another project with Yoman and then use configure-sso npm command, I get :

```
Error: Unable to set tenant reply urls.
ERROR: Bad Request({"error":{"code":"Request_BadRequest","message":"Invalid object identifier 'undefined'.","innerError":{"date":"2022-10-12T07:00:11","request-id":"972a0b4e-2691-4fe7-a8c6-1f247c2333f5","client-request-id":"972a0b4e-2691-4fe7-a8c6-1f247c2333f5"}}})
```

Comment: What version of Office are you using? Have you seen this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/troubleshoot-sso-in-office-add-ins  And see also https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/requirement-sets/common/identity-api-requirement-sets?view=excel-js-preview

Comment: Absolutely I have seen this and I am using the latest office suite direct for office.com

Comment: Just cannot seem to figure out what’s up with it

Comment: I'm still not clear on the version. Are you testing with Office on Windows, Office on Mac, Office Online, Office perpetual (non-subscription)?

Comment: I am testing with office on windows

Comment: Hi @RickKirkham - I have updated the body with a screenshot on the version... thanks

Comment: I don't see a screenshot.

Comment: @RickKirkham - its there now - thanks a lot for this.

Comment: I have updated my code to reflect that I can get access IdentityAPI version 1.3 on my client - so I should be able to access SSO. Can anyone please help further?

Comment: Where and when do you try to use Identity API 1.3 in the add-in? Is it an event based add-in?

Comment: It isn’t an event based add-in

Comment: Is this still happening for you? That error usually indicates that something is missing from the WebApplicationInfo (notably the id or resources node, but it appears that you have it in there). Do you have the full manifest that others could try and see if they hit the same issue as you? (or a manifest that repros the error). Perhaps, there is a chance that the manifest isn't being actually updated on the Exchange Server? You can see what outlook downloaded (and is using) by going to:

Comment: C:\Users\[username]\AppData\Local\microsoft\office\16.0\wef\{A98BE375-791E-4897-A0DB-B890ACCD00C6}\jsdiOrZEwLFvkmFYeSA0fQ==\Manifests

Note that the [username] will be your own userna,e and the GUID and Base64 encoding  will be unique to your machine as well. You can have several of these folders on your machine if you have multiple outlook profiles or exchange accounts. If you have several you can either find the right one, or just delete the folder and Outlook will recreate it on boot.

Comment: share [code, data and error tracebacks as text, not images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors/285557#285557)

Answer (score 1):

I still don't know exactly what was causing this issue, but I found that changing the following properties under the OfficeApp section in the manifest suddenly caused it to work:

- Id
- ProviderName
- DisplayName
- Description
- SupportUrl
- AppDomains

I suspect the most likely candidates for the fix was Id, ProviderName or AppDomains. My only guess is because I had copied over a demo application to be the base for my new application (but had not changed some of these properties in the manifest), the token retrieval failed because the token request inputs differed slightly to the cached one. Just a guess...

Best recommendation is to make sure you're changing these all of these values when you're doing development off a demo app!

Answer (score 0):

The Outlook version specified should support the Identity API 1.3 requirement set. See [Outlook client support](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/requirement-sets/outlook/outlook-api-requirement-sets?view=excel-js-preview&tabs=xmlmanifest#outlook-client-support) for all supported versions.

Also you my find your Outlook version listed in the [Update History](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/officeupdates/current-channel-preview#version-2209-september-23) page.

Try to scaffold a new add-in project and then use the `configure-sso` package to configure it for using SSO like described in the [Single sign-on (SSO) quick start](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/quickstarts/sso-quickstart).

Comment: Yep I have checked for identity api and it’s there

Comment: I cannot use the sso package because I am using azure Active Directory and  not the temporary azure thingy and it moans about the local certificate

Comment: Yeah you have tk use Microsoft m365 tenant on this example - is there a way of just using azure like normal azure ? I have not got involved in m365 tenant …. Can anyone help me ??

Comment: I have attempted to scaffold a project and use configuew-sso and the error is on my main question - can you please suggest further ? Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar issue, and I had to ensure the appropriate VersionOverides are specified. In your manifest, it seems version 1.1 may not be specified appropriately. Try updating to the following:

```
<VersionOverrides xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides" xsi:type="VersionOverridesV1_0">
  <VersionOverrides xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides/1.1" xsi:type="VersionOverridesV1_1">
    <Hosts>
      <Host xsi:type="MailHost">
        <DesktopFormFactor>
          <FunctionFile resid="Commands.Url"/>
          <ExtensionPoint xsi:type="MessageReadCommandSurface">
            <OfficeTab id="TabDefault">
              <Group id="msgReadGroup">
                <Label resid="GroupLabel"/>
                <Control xsi:type="Button" id="msgReadOpenPaneButton">
                  <Label resid="TaskpaneButton.Label"/>
                  <Supertip>
                    <Title resid="TaskpaneButton.Label"/>
                    <Description resid="TaskpaneButton.Tooltip"/>
                  </Supertip>
                  <Icon>
                    <bt:Image size="16" resid="Icon.16x16"/>
                    <bt:Image size="32" resid="Icon.32x32"/>
                    <bt:Image size="80" resid="Icon.80x80"/>
                  </Icon>
                  <Action xsi:type="ShowTaskpane">
                    <SourceLocation resid="Taskpane.Url"/>
                  </Action>
                </Control>
                <Control xsi:type="Button" id="ActionButton">
                  <Label resid="ActionButton.Label"/>
                  <Supertip>
                    <Title resid="ActionButton.Label"/>
                    <Description resid="ActionButton.Tooltip"/>
                  </Supertip>
                  <Icon>
                    <bt:Image size="16" resid="Icon.16x16"/>
                    <bt:Image size="32" resid="Icon.32x32"/>
                    <bt:Image size="80" resid="Icon.80x80"/>
                  </Icon>
                  <Action xsi:type="ExecuteFunction">
                    <FunctionName>action</FunctionName>
                  </Action>
                </Control>
              </Group>
            </OfficeTab>
          </ExtensionPoint>
        </DesktopFormFactor>
      </Host>
    </Hosts>
    <Resources>
      <bt:Images>
        <bt:Image id="Icon.16x16" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/assets/icon-16.png"/>
        <bt:Image id="Icon.32x32" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/assets/icon-32.png"/>
        <bt:Image id="Icon.80x80" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/assets/icon-80.png"/>
      </bt:Images>
      <bt:Urls>
        <bt:Url id="Commands.Url" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/commands.html"/>
        <bt:Url id="Taskpane.Url" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/taskpane.html"/>
      </bt:Urls>
      <bt:ShortStrings>
        <bt:String id="GroupLabel" DefaultValue="Contoso Add-in"/>
        <bt:String id="TaskpaneButton.Label" DefaultValue="Show Taskpane"/>
        <bt:String id="ActionButton.Label" DefaultValue="Perform an action"/>
      </bt:ShortStrings>
      <bt:LongStrings>
        <bt:String id="TaskpaneButton.Tooltip" DefaultValue="Opens a pane displaying all available properties."/>
        <bt:String id="ActionButton.Tooltip" DefaultValue="Perform an action when clicked."/>
      </bt:LongStrings>
    </Resources>
    <WebApplicationInfo>
        <Id>{Client_ID}</Id>
        <Resource>api://localhost:3000/{Client_ID}</Resource>
        <Scopes>
          <Scope>Files.Read</Scope>
          <Scope>openid</Scope>
          <Scope>profile</Scope>
        </Scopes>
  </WebApplicationInfo>
  </VersionOverrides>
  </VersionOverrides>
</OfficeApp>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the WebApplicationInfo is a child element of the VersionOverrides element in the manifest. This was the issue for me.