# OfficeJS Manifest Type MailApp with WebApplicationInfo is having deployment errors from VS 2022

Tags: outlook, single-sign-on, office-js, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

I am using VS 2022 and I am trying to implement SSO with Office Add-in, but as soon as I add

```
<VersionOverrides xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides/1.1"
xsi:type="VersionOverridesV1_1">
    <WebApplicationInfo>
      <Id>guid</Id>
      <Resource>api://localhost:3000//guid</Resource>
      <Scopes>
        <Scope>Files.Read</Scope>
        <Scope>profile</Scope>
        <Scope>openid</Scope>
     </Scopes>
   </WebApplicationInfo>
<VersionOverrides>
```

I am getting error popup during debug. I am not able to see any issues in the output.

Without above section, add-in is building and I can run in debug.

Do I need to add anything else?

[image]

[image]

or with
[image]

App is registered with following permissions:
[image]

I am trying to get access token and currently response is:

```
The identity API is not supported for this add-in.

async function getUserData() {
    try {
        let userTokenEncoded = await OfficeRuntime.auth.getAccessToken();
        let userToken = jwt_decode(userTokenEncoded); // Using the https://www.npmjs.com/package/jwt-decode library.
        console.log(userToken.name); // user name
        console.log(userToken.preferred_username); // email
        console.log(userToken.oid); // user id     
    }
    catch (exception) {
        console.log(exception);
        if (exception.code === 13003) {
            // SSO is not supported for domain user accounts, only
            // Microsoft 365 Education or work account, or a Microsoft account.
            popup.showNotification("test");
        }
        if (exception.code === 13000) {
            // SSO is not supported for domain user accounts, only
            // Microsoft 365 Education or work account, or a Microsoft account.
            popup.showNotification(exception.message);
        }
        else {
            // Handle error
            popup.showNotification("test");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74019738/the-identity-api-is-not-supported-for-this-add-in-error-code-13000-outlook

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your add-in was registered with an identity platform, see [Register an Office Add-in that uses single sign-on (SSO) with the Microsoft identity platform](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/register-sso-add-in-aad-v2) for more information.

In `VSCode` to register your application and then configure the manifest file of your add-in automatically you may use the following command:

```
"configure-sso": "office-addin-sso configure manifest.xml",
```

See the [office-addin-sso](https://www.npmjs.com/package/office-addin-sso) node package for more information.

Note, this command will fail if your tenant is configured to require two-factor authentication. In this scenario, you'll need to manually complete the Azure app registration and SSO configuration steps by following all the steps in the [Create a Node.js Office Add-in that uses single sign-on](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/create-sso-office-add-ins-nodejs) tutorial.

Also I'd suggest scaffolding a new solution using the Yeoman generator which includes the SSO part out of the box and then try to register it using the Node package mentioned in my post earlier. Following that way you will find out what is the difference between the sample manifest and yours.

Comment: is there a way to add office-addin-sso when you are using VS 2022? App is registered, but still I am getting same issue. Also, if I put <VersionOverrides xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides" xsi:type="VersionOverridesV1_0">
     <VersionOverrides xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides/1.1"
    xsi:type="VersionOverridesV1_1"> I am having issues

Comment: That is a node package which makes sense only for NodeJS based solutions.

Comment: Have you tried to validate the manifest file? What errors do you get in that case?

Comment: I'd suggest scaffolding a new solution using the Yeoman generator which includes the SSO part out of the box and try to register it using the Node package mentioned in my post. Following that way you will find out what is the difference between the sample manifest and yours.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what Eugene says in his answer, it appears that your `<VersionOverrides ... type ... 1_1>` has only a `<WebApplicationInfo>` child. There are two required child elments that you need to have, `<Hosts>` and `<Resources>`. For more information about `<VersionOverrides 1_1>`, see [VersionOverrides 1.1 element in the manifest file for a mail add-in](https://learn.microsoft.com/javascript/api/manifest/versionoverrides-1-1-mail).